# Corrupt external Hard Drive

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, data-corruption

after plugging in my Hard Drive to to a Windows 10 PC it got corrupt. i'm using Ubuntu 20.4 and it only shows when i open **Disk**. but the only options i get are

1. Format Partition
2. Create Partition Image
3. Restore Partition Image
4. Benchmark Partition

i want to know if is there a way to fix the drive without losing the data.

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Please take a screenshot of **Disks** and upload it to imgur.com. then [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1278106/edit) and add a link to the screenshot.

Comment: not quite sure how to do that. i've been trying

Comment: what is your definition of "corrupted"? "unclean" is something else: unplugged while active. That you need to fix from windows if it is ntfs: checkdisk.

Comment: i'm not quite sure what happened to it but it might have been unplugged while still active. so is there a way to fix in on windows?

Comment: See [something like this](https://neosmart.net/wiki/chkdsk/#From_Command_Prompt-5). Replace `C:` with the drive letter of your external drive.

Comment: the drive i want to fix does not even show the drive path. meaning i there isn't C: or any other letter